# How to iterate over pages in pdf and give each page as input to tika

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, apache-tika

I have multiple pdf files which have images (scanned copies of papers) in it and when I use the tika parser (included the Tesseract OCR Config in tika) It was unable to extract text from pdf ,But when I split each page of pdf into image files and If I give each of the image file as input to tika then it is able to extract the text from the image.

below are the dependencies which I am using

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.levigo.jbig2</groupId>
  <artifactId>levigo-jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
  <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
  <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
  <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>
```

and below is my code

```
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    TesseractOCRConfig ocrConfig = new TesseractOCRConfig();

    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    PDFParserConfig pdfConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
    pdfConfig.setExtractInlineImages(true);
    pdfConfig.setExtractUniqueInlineImagesOnly(false);
    ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();

    ocrConfig.setLanguage("eng");       
    ocrConfig.setTesseractPath("C:\\workarea\\teseract\\Tesseract-OCR");
    ocrConfig.setTessdataPath("C:\\workarea\\teseract\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata");

    parseContext.set(Parser.class, parser);
    parseContext.set(PDFParserConfig.class, pdfConfig);
    parseContext.set(TesseractOCRConfig.class, ocrConfig);


    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, parseContext);
    String text = handler.toString().trim();
```

Even I tried setting the tesseract location and tessdata location in my code,But it didn't work.

I checked whether tesseract is installed properly on my machine or not then this was the output

```
 C:\workarea\teseract\Tesseract-OCR>tesseract --version
   tesseract 3.02
   leptonica-1.68 (Mar 14 2011, 10:43:03) [MSC v.1500 LIB Release 32 bit]
   libgif 4.1.6 : libjpeg 8c : libpng 1.4.3 : libtiff 3.9.4 : zlib 1.2.5
```

I am thinking to iterate over the pages in pdf and give the inputstream object of each page to tika for extracting the text. Is this the right way to do ? (OR) Are there any other ways for parsing the text from a pdf(which has scanned copies of papers) using tika.

Comment: Bump your Apache Tika version up to the latest supported one (1.24) and try again?

Comment: @Gagravarr I have tried it with 1.24 (tika-parsers) dependency,It didn't work

Comment: Did you try following the tips and setup in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaOCR ?